# Efficiently query core data with array of strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, regex, core-data

Let me explain what I want to do here.

I'm using OCR to recognise text on an image. Not all words are recognised correctly and most of the time it's one or two letters that are wrong in a word.
I have a database of the correct words that should be recognised stored in Core Data. So, I figured that I could match each word that is recognised against my data in Core Data to 'fix' the few letters that aren't recognised correctly.

The way I would handle it, is by doing the following:

```
Store every recognised word in an array of strings 

for every string in array
    query to entity 
    if found
         change word to the one matching in entity
    else
         do different query
```

Only this doesn't seem very efficient for me. I need to query Core Data for every word separately.
And besides that I don't know if it's possible to query my Entity for words that differ 1 or 2 characters.

I'm pretty new to Core Data and I want to do it correctly from the start and teach myself best practices.

So here are my questions. Is it possible to query an array of strings to Core Data without using a for loop (maybe with a method that's already in the SDK)?
How should my NSPredicate be constructed like when I want to match a string that differs 1 or 2 characters that could be at any position in the string?

Comment: How many words do you have in Core Data?

Comment: I have 597 entities that have a 'name' attribute which i want to compare to

Comment: So, 600 entries x 10 letters = 6kB, why not just load them into an array where access is much faster?

Comment: "want to match a string that differs 1 or 2 characters that could be at any position in the string" That is a difficult problem.

Comment: Because that only applies to my current case. I want to learn the best practise for this problem so I could apply it to a future app where I may have a larger database.

Comment: you should use "fuzzy matching" and learn about "levenshtein distance"

Comment: thank you very much. that's exactly what i was looking for! seems like it's pretty hard, but I'll give it a try. If not I found some fuzzy search libraries.